# Problem with the inverse expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $q=e^{2\pi i z}$ and $t=q-12q^2+66q^3-220q^4+495q^5-...$ Then why is the inverse expansion equal to $q=t+12t^2+222t^3+...$? I also do not understand the notation here: $t$ means $t(z)$ or $t(q)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to know anything about variable $z$ and the relation between $q$ and $z$ in order to solve this problem.

Just think that $q, t$ are variables connected by equation $$t = q - 12q^{2} + 66q^{3} - 220q^{4} + 495q^{5} - \cdots\tag{1}$$ and the problem here is find $q$ in terms of a power series in $t$. Let us assume that $$q = a_{0} + a_{1}t + a_{2}t^{2} + a_{3}t^{3} + \cdots\tag{2}$$ and we will find the numbers $a_{k}$ one by one. Clearly from $(1)$ we can see that if $q = 0$ then $t = 0$ and hence put $t = 0$ in $(2)$ we get $a_{0} = 0$ and hence $$q = a_{1}t + a_{2}t^{2} + \cdots$$ Putting this value of $q$ in $(1)$ we get $$t = (a_{1}t + a_{2}t^{2} + \cdots) - 12(a_{1}t + a_{2}t^{2} + \cdots)^{2} + \cdots = a_{1}t + (a_{2} - 12a_{1})t^{2} + \cdots$$ Hence by comparing coefficients of $t$ and $t^{2}$ on both sides we get $a_{1} = 1$ and $a_{2} = 12a_{1} = 12$. It is possible to apply the same technique (with more calculation effort to find $a_{3}, a_{4}, \cdots$. Thus for $a_{3}$ you will need to perform calculations such that we calculate coefficients till $t^{3}$. Note that calculation of $a_{k}$ will depend on the values of previously calculated $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{k - 1}$.

So far we have calculated $a_{1}, a_{2}$ above and from that we get $q = t + 12t^{2} + \cdots$.

Comment: Thanks again for your support! You say "if $q=0$ then $t=0$. But $q$ could not be $0$. I don't get your point.

Comment: @R.A.: If $t = 0$ then one possible value of $q$ is $0$. Using this we are able to express this one possible value of $q$ in terms of power series of $t$. More formally the relation $(1)$ between $q$ and $t$ is invertible or not needs to be seen. From $(1)$ it is possible to show that the relation is invertible for values of $q$ in a neighborhood of $0$ because $dt/dq \neq 0$ in such neighborhood.